# Set and access view bindings in handlebars

Tags: ember.js

Is there a way to set a binding in handlebars for a view and then use that in the template?

```
{{view App.SKillView skillBinding="Skill1"}}
```

and then in the template use that binding such as:

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="skill">
     <h5>{{skill}}</h5>
     <div {{action spendPoints skill 1}}></div>
</script>
```

The view class is really simple:

```
App.SkillView = Ember.View.extend({
    templateName:'skill',
    classNames: ['skill']
});
```

These seems really simple, but for the life of me I can't figure it out.  Any help would be appreciated.  I basically want to be able to dynamically reuse the same view through my `App` and have it affect different `skills` in each place.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're pretty much there, you just need to access the properties via the view

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="skill">
  <h5>{{view.skill}}</h5>
  <div {{action spendPoints view.skill 1}} href="#"></div>
</script>
```

Comment: That's how I thought it should work, as well, but it does not.  Any idea why?

Comment: Can you put together a fiddle I assume your `skillBinding=""` definition should probably just be `skill=""`

Comment: That did it! Thank you!  It's just skill="skill1".

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried adding `attributeBindings: ['skill']` to your view?

Comment: Thank you for responding!  Just gave that a shot and it didn't work.