# Dynamically set properties on a view from Handlebars

Tags: ember.js

I'm trying to DRY up my templates by creating views for common layout elements. I have the following views defined

```
App.SplitListView = Em.View.extend({
    tagName: 'div',
    classNames: [ 'panel', 'panel-default' ]
});

App.SplitListHeaderView = Em.View.extend({
    classNames: [ 'panel-heading' ],

    templateName: 'split-list-header-view-layout'
});
```

The template for the `SplitListView` is a simple `{{yield}}`

The template for the `SplitListHeaderView` is

```
<span class="panel-title">{{view.headerText}}</span>
{{#if view.showCreateButton}}
    <span class="pull-right">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm">
            <i class="fa fa-plus fa-lg" style="padding-right: 10px;"></i>{{view.createButtonText}}
        </button>
    </span>
{{/if}}
```

Then the template for the submodule:

```
{{#view App.SplitListView}}
    {{view App.SplitListHeaderView headerTextBinding="Sandwiches" showCreateButtonBinding=true createButtonTextBinding="Make me a sandwich!"}}
{{/view}}
```

The desired end result is that I'd like to use the `SplitListView` and `SplitListHeaderView` everywhere in my app that I use that layout and just set the relevant bits of text via the controller. But so far it's just not working. I feel like this should be easy to do and I'm just missing something. I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16574349/set-and-access-view-bindings-in-handlebars) which looks to be along the same lines as my question but the solution did not work for me.

Does anyone have any experience with something like this or am I off my rocker in trying to use views in this manner?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you have three options here:

1) Use a component instead of a view. Components are reusable, self-contained 'modules' that allow you to bind properties from the component's context in exactly the same manner as you are trying with your view.

2) If the only thing you're reusing between the current non-DRY templates is the html/handlebars you should use a `{{partial}}` instead of a view because that doesn't create any scope within the view hierarchy and will allow you to bind the handlebars in the partial directly to route's view/controller properties without specifying additional property bindings or scope.

3) Use a `Em.Handlebars.helper` to accept three arguments (headerText, buttonText, and showCreateButton) and return a `new Handlebars.SafeString('some html string');` or something along those lines.

### **A solution**

If I were you, I would utilize methods 2 and 3 together as follows:

First, use a helper (I'm using a helper with a globally accessible method) instead of `App.SplitListView` to wrap some html around the buffer (i.e. content) inside of the opening and closing handlebars:

```
// Handy method you can use across many different areas of the app
// to wrap content in simple html
Utils.wrapBuffer = function(open, close, options, context) {
  options.data.buffer.push('\n' + open);

  if (options.fn(context)) {
    options.data.buffer.push('\n' + options.fn(context));
  }

  options.data.buffer.push('\n' + close);
}
```

Then the actual helper

```
App.Handlebars.helper('split-list', function(options) {
  var open = '<div class="panel panel-default">;
  var close = '</div>';

  Utils.wrapBuffer(open, close, options, this);
});
```

Now, your template will look like:

```
{{#split-list}}
  // This is where our content will go
{{/split-list}}
```

This has the advantage of wrapping what is inbetween the handlebars opening and closing tags with html without adding or changing scope. Thus, property bindings will work seamlessly.

Now, replace `App.SplitListheaderView` with a component set up in a similar manner:

```
App.SplitListHeaderComponent = Em.Component.extend({
  classNames: ['panel-heading'],
  headerText: null,
  createButtonText: null,
  showCreateButton: false,
});
```

You layout (components use layouts, not templates) will be located at `templates/components/split-list-header.hbs`. it will look as follows:

```
<span class="panel-title">{{headerText}}</span>
{{#if showCreateButton}}
    <span class="pull-right">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm">
            <i class="fa fa-plus fa-lg" style="padding-right: 10px;"></i>{{createButtonText}}
        </button>
    </span>
{{/if}}
```

Note, that properties are `something` not `view.something` and each property is declared allowing it to be overwritten in the handlebars helper. Now your submodule's template will look like:

```
{{#split-list}}
  {{split-list-header
    headerText='Sandwiches'
    showCreateButton=true
    createButtonText='Make me a sandwich!'
  }}
{{/split-list}}
```

If you wanted, you could bing these properties to a property on your controller or view instead of writing them in the template every time.

### **Another Improvement**

You could go one step further and scrap the wrapping helper all together because it's not doing anything except adding HTML. In this case, the component would look like `{{split-list headerText=blah...}}` and would have the following template:

```
<div class="panel-heading">
  <span class="panel-title">{{view.headerText}}</span>
  {{#if view.showCreateButton}}
    <span class="pull-right">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm">
        <i class="fa fa-plus fa-lg" style="padding-right: 10px;"></i>{{view.createButtonText}}
      </button>
    </span>
  {{/if}}
</div>
```

Comment: Duncan - thanks for the detailed response! A couple of questions...I thought about using a component but the primary function of the `split-list-view` is to have a list of selectable items. Selecting the item will then render that items template in an outlet contained in the parent view. A good example is the interface for outlook.com. the `split-list-view` is the left side of that interface and the selected item from that list would be render into the larger right side of the interface. Would a component still work in that scenario?

Comment: Ok. There's a few ways you could achieve that but I would probably use an `Em.CollectionView` with the above template for each button be the template of each `childView`. In the template for that child view I'd have an action that binds the object or a property of the object to a property on the controller. For example: `{{action 'setSelection' headerText}}` with the `actions: {setSelection: function(name) {this.set('selectionName', name); }` or something like that. I can explain more over email or maybe do a jsbin if you like

Comment: Thanks! Marked your original comment as the answer!

Comment: Ok, thanks - glad to help! Alternatively, if your controller's content is the list of 'selectable' objects a simple partial containing an action-bounded button inside an `{{#each}}` may suffice. So long as you're not creating unnecessary scope your approach is probably reasonable.